# Enter Data Into a PHP File, Using PHP

Tags: php, file, fwrite

This is the same project as the other question I had.

I'm wondering how to use a .php to enter data into a CERTAIN LOCATION to another php file, so think of it as remotely adding in data.

I've Googled, and haven't found much, and I'm sure I got the php editing down, I'm just clueless on how I would enter the data into a specific point.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

// Parameters (Leave this Alone)
 $Message = $_GET["message"];
 $Username = htmlspecialchars($_GET["username"]);
 $time = ($_GET["time"]);

// User Banning
$data = file_get_contents('Banned.txt');
if(strpos($data, $Username) !== FALSE)
{
    die();
}
else
   {
// --------------- Staff Members ---------------- //
// Admins //
  If ($Username=="!divider!user")  $Username="!divider![Admin] user"; 
   If ($Username=="!divider!user2")  $Username="!divider![Admin] user2"; 


// File Writing (Leave this Alone) 
 $File = "Chat.txt"; 
 $Handle = fopen($File, "a"); 
 fwrite($Handle, $Username);
 fwrite($Handle, ": ");
 fwrite($Handle, $Message);
   fwrite($Handle, " -:-:- ");
 fwrite($Handle, $time);
 fwrite($Handle, "\r\n");
 print "Data Written"; 
 fclose($Handle); 
 }
 ?>
```

I'm trying to use another php file, to add staff under the staff list.

So in (edit.php) have a textarea input, and whatever I submit, it enters the submitted data under:

```
    //-----Staff Members-----//
```

the client I will be using will fill in everything in front and behind of the username for php.

Comment: So... what are you trying to do exactly?Put something into something else to do something?

Comment: And what is this same project you had in the other question you had? You're not alone posting on SO.

Comment: I dont know what happend, hold up, Half of my post didnt post, I had a Source posted. wtf

Comment: Be more precise,your question is not at all clear.. :(

Comment: Careful, code that changes itself is the first step to the robot uprising! :p

Comment: @Kolink i tried that one, make a javascript AI that auto updates it's source code, was slow as hell, maybe i could do something out with Chrome's speed today...

Comment: Generally speaking, it would be better to write your data into some other (non-PHP-source-code) file. Writing data into a file that is then interpreted and executed is a path toward many insidious and dangerous bugs. Writing data into a .txt or .csv file helps keep the data apart from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but it sounds like you want to add another php file somewhere in your code. You could user `require`, `require_once` or `include` to handle this:

```
require_once('file-name-here.php');
```